# I am creating a text game on python and have a question about variables across functions

Tags: python, python-requests

I am just starting out and want to try and make the game depend on if "sword" is set to true. but when I run it, it doesn't return anything even though the value has been defined. this is just a small snippet of my code where the problem lies.

```
def fight():
    import time
    sword = False
    user = input()
    if user == "run":
        print("pick it up or leave it?")
        user = input()
        if user == "pick it up":
            sword = True
            print("fight or flee")
            fight2()

        elif user == "leave it":
            print("you leave the sword")
            #PATH OPEN
    return sword

def fight2():
    import time
    user = input()
    if user == "fight":
        if fight():
            print("you fight the dragon")

        elif not fight():
            print("you have no sword")
            #PATH OPEN
fight()
```

I need help so the `if fight():`, it will run. right now it just returns nothing when the user types "fight". thanks!

Comment: Your functions are huge! Code gets pretty hard to read pretty quickly if you have functions that big, which is probably why you missed the return statement there x). Try subdividing them into smaller meaningful subroutines. Also, refrain from comparing things to True or False on if statements, go for `if fight2()` or `if not fight2()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You function fight2 has no return statement. By default, it returns None, which is falsey.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of retuning sword, just return T/F if you want to execute another function based on fight2()

Also, `if not f(x)` is equivalent to `if f(x) == False`

Same with `if f(x)` and `if f(x) == True`

Comment: can you give me an example of what I should do? I changed it so it only returns True or False and I got rid of "if f(x) == True". It is still not returning anything

Comment: not really sure what you mean. if f(x) returns something, then you can set a variable y equal to f(x) and y will be equal to "something"

Comment: when i call "fight2()" in the function fight3 it does not give me the text it is supposed to, it just stops. I am trying to use the variable "sword" in fight3 but define it in fight2

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, your control flow is incomplete.  Should be more like this:

```
def fight2():
   sword = False # default value
   user = input()
   if user == 'run':
      # do stuff
   elif user == "slide":
      # do stuff
   else:
      # bad input, what to do?
   return sword
```

The goal is that no matter what the inputs, the function should hit a return statement.  Personally, I like to have only one return statements, which can make it easier to debug, but you can have multiple returns.